# Как при удалении последнего товара переадресовывать на шаблон с пустой корзиной?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Есть интернет-магазин на `wordpress+woocommerce`.
У меня есть разные шаблоны для корзины с товарами и пустой корзиной. 
Такой вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы при удалении последнего товара выполнялась переадресация на шаблон с пустой корзиной, а не просто в корзине появлялась строчка "ваша корзина пуста", причем в поле итого сумма изменяется только теперь почему-то при обновлении корзины, а не сразу (получаем такой неприятный момент, когда фактически товаров в корзине нет и пишет пусто, а сумма при ajax не обновляется).

```
/**
 * Handle when a remove item link is clicked.
 *
 * @param {Object} evt The JQuery event
 */
item_remove_clicked: function( evt ) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    var $a = $( evt.currentTarget );
    var $form = $a.parents( 'form' );

    block( $form );
    block( $( 'div.cart_totals' ) );

    $.ajax( {
        type:     'GET',
        url:      $a.attr( 'href' ),
        dataType: 'html',
        success: update_wc_div,
        complete: function() {
            unblock( $form );
            unblock( $( 'div.cart_totals' ) );
        }
    } );
}
```

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение - привязался к триггеру `updated_wc_div`

```
$('body').on('updated_wc_div',function() {
    location.reload(); // uncomment this line to refresh the page.
});
```